# Kali network keeps dropping/dying

Tags: networking, kali-linux, debian

Running Kali 2.0 on VMWare Fusion 10.1.1 on MacBook Pro laptop running macOS 10.13.6. I'm running the newtwork from VMWare in the NAT mode. I was able to connect to the internet, had an IPV4 address via ifconfig and basically happy.

Now, my network "drops/dies". I lose my IPV4 address, i.e. no longer get an IPV4 address via ifconfig. Can't ping anything on the outside or use FireFox. From within Kali my network icon disappears from the top right. At the host level I'm still able to work and connect normally.

The only thing I've been able to do to resolve my issue is revert to an older snapshot. After I revert to the snapshot I'm able to work normally for a period of time, 15 minutes to a couple of hours and then my problem appears again and I lose connectivity.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Although Kali has a lot of security tools, it is just a Linux distribution. So, this is a Linux networking question and not a security question.

Answer (score 0):

In Kali, your network stack is managed by a Network Manager (that doesn't conform to ifconfig commands).  So what's happening is that when you make your ifconfig changes, they are overwritten the next time NetworkManager checks to make sure it's config is represented.

You have at least two options:

1. Kill NetworkManager after each boot so that when you use ifconfig, the ip/subnetmask will stay
2. Use the GUI NetworkManager to manage the interface(s)

Either way will work, possibly others, but I use the previous two methods a lot because of this problem.